# How do I transfer a variable's value from a 2nd form to the 1st form?

Tags: c#, winforms

In C#, let's say there are two forms: the first and the second.  The first form is what the program starts by using, and it basically is the overlord in relation to the other forms. The second form is a specific-use thing that will spawn modally (correct word?) when a certain button is clicked on the first form.  All the second form does is get a selection from the user.  It can be represented easily as either an int or a string.  Now when that second form closes (which happens when the user hits the only button on that form to lock in their choice), there's the little issue about that variable which stored the choice being lost without ever being copied over to the first form.  How do I alleviate this problem?  I would prefer for the variable to actually only be in the class of the first form, not the second, unless that would cause more than a couple of extra lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two forms. Form1 and Form2. Form2 spawns modally, using ShowWindow(this), this parameter insures Form2 that only the form Form1 has spawned it, so in that case, it sets up internal properties (for short). As a plus, properties are declarerd internal, for use in one assembly, and writeable by Form2 only.

The best way to achieve desired result is like that.

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //declate private varliables
        int parameter1;
        string parameter2;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // create form
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            if (form2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // if the button is pressed
                parameter1 = form2.Parameter1;
                parameter2 = form2.Parameter2;
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {        
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //declate internal parameters
        internal int Parameter1 { get; private set; }
        internal string Parameter2 { get; private set; }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // if the button is pressed
            Form1 form1 = this.Owner as Form1;
            if (form1 != null) 
            {
                // sets the local parameters
                Parameter1 = -1;
                Parameter2 = "John Doe";

                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Everybody so far has had what appears to be a correct and useful answer, but you spelled out some of the details (in addition to showing some stuff in your code that I almost immediately need to look up).  Thanks.

Comment: Why should Form2 depend on Form1? It should set the parameters regardless of who called it.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Ok, i have added some text to explain my solution. Fixed ;)

Comment: @John Saunders: Form2 is no dependent on Form1. It does not use anything from Form1 but the name. So they aren't.

Comment: @Artur: "Form1 form1 = this.Owner as Form1;" is a dependency. Remove it and your answer is correct.

Comment: @John Saunders: Please explain why you are calling this a dependency. If so, can i say that Form2 is also dependent on implementation of Form1? I think that implemenmtation specific (behavioral) dependency matter for this case.

Comment: You are correct but some changes like,  you are not using form1(instance) further, so it is not necessary. In all you are not using Owner anywhere in second form so it can be removed.

Comment: @alliswell: No, I am using Owner when call .ShowDialog(this). This (this) parameter is of type of Form1 for the clarity. So, it is required though.

Comment: @John Saunders: No, it should not set the parameters regardless of who called it, because these forms supposed to be in some kind of form specific. And they must be externally visible in the bound of assembly. Moreover proerties in From2 must be read-only (if so, writeable only by Form2) for the known reasons, you know.

Comment: Ya correct so in this situation you can directly say Form1 form1 = this.Owner as Form1;form.parameter = "something. So properties defined in form2 is not really needed. BUT I would suggest to remove Owner dependancy completely and just set form2 properties. Anyhow form1(or others who will call) will use form2 properties.

Comment: @alliswell: Firstly, propably you are right, but that is not a requirements nor specified in question. Yes, it can be completely independent, but continuing thinkning in such the way, than why should Form2 spawns modally? The answer is that the lifetime of object Form2 is less than lifetime of Form1. if so, that is a some kind of lifecycle deplendency. Secondly, if somewone will change or read properties of Form2 how do you know that that information will be used for a good, not evil, goal? For example, if virus (or another addin, piece of junky code form another programmer) create Form2?

Comment: @Artur: designing windows forms applications to avoid viruses doesn't make much sense. If you want to "protect" the form, then make the form class `internal`. Then it can only be used within the same assembly. Also, by allowing Form2 to be independent on who calls it, you have much greater flexibility if you turn out later to need to call it from elsewhere.

Comment: @John Saunders: It is your design decisions, not mine. I will stay with my point of view, because I had so many times such a case that other programs used my Forms inproperly, that I still think that in this case Form1 and Form2 are specific to each other. If and only if later in time it will be required that Form2 must be data-aware, independent of the code it will raise, and data it stores, i will definetely do what you say, but in this case only. At least, you have good idea, bu how do you explain that this form has the same properties as in caller form Form1?

Comment: @Artur: I don't explain it because the OP didn't say why it was the case. However, it's possible that Form1 has those properties as "the values I collected from Form2".

Answer (score 1):

Forms are classes. They can have public properties. Have the first form create the second form, then set a property with the variable's value. The second form can then use the property.

Comment: The trouble with that is that when the second form closes, the variable is deleted with the rest of the class.  I'm not sure how to use the first class's code to gather that data while only the 2nd is usable.

Comment: There are so many ways for the first form creat second form, and then Show it using 3 different methods, there are so many ways to declare a property (internal, public, read-only, write-only) that your answer is inappropriate for that child question

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Agreed. Look into my solution ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The comment above just comes from my newbish nature with C#.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correcly then you want to update FORM1 values FROM FORM2 so you can use either of following way, [Parent Form](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/32436-best-way-to-update-parent-form-after-child-form-clos)() or [Delegate](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mosessaur/winformsdelegates09042006094826am/winformsdelegates.aspx) to update.

To use parent form you need something like,

```
           (ParentForm as Form1).MyProperty = 123;
           //This will work if you working in MDI like scenario.
```

I would suggest to use delegate.